# Method prints correct data but returns unedited data in Go

Tags: go, methods

This is my second day of learning Go and I'm trying to better understand structs and methods, so apologies in advance if this questions is a bit basic. Why does this program print the edited data inside the method, but by the time it gets back to main, what's printed is the original data passed to the struct?

```
package main
import ( "fmt" )

type Person struct{
    firstName string
    lastName string
}

func (p Person) updateName(newName string) string{
    p.firstName = newName
    fmt.Println(p.firstName, p.lastName) //prints "Jane Doe"
    return newName + " " + p.lastName
}

func main() {
    p := Person{"John", "Doe"}
    p.updateName("Jane")
    fmt.Println(p) //prints "{John Doe}"
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use pointer receiver: `func (p *Person) updateName(...)`

Comment: Read this page about methods in the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/methods/4)